# What is the relation between these two subgroups of a finite cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $a$. If $k$, $m$ are integers such that gcd($n, m$) = gcd($n,k$), then what is the relationship between the subgroups generated by $a^k$ and $a^m$?

Comment: Have you tried computing some examples?

Comment: If two groups have a relationship between order, what does that tell you about their characteristic?

Comment: @DonLarynx what do you mean by characteristic of a group?

Comment: The characteristic $m$ of a group is how many times $1*1*1...*1 = 0$ $m$ times, * an arbitrary operator.

Comment: @DonLarynx No, that is the characteristic of a ring. A group will not have both a $1$ and a $0$ (usually).

Comment: Tobias Kildetoft, I can certainly compute, but that won't conclusively prove anything. Working with $Z_{12}$, for example, I can say that $\langle a^3 \rangle$ $=$  $\langle a^9 \rangle$.

Comment: Well, have you computed enough examples to arrive at a guess about what the relation might be?

Comment: Don Larynx, I'm afraid I have no idea of what you're talking about. I've heard only about the characteristic of a ring but never about that of a group.

Comment: Tobias Kildetoft, I wonder if the two subgroups are equal. If so, how to give a rigorous proof?

Comment: Try to prove that they are both equal to the subgroup generated by $a^d$ where $d$ is the gcd of $k$ and $n$ (and hence also the gcd of $m$ and $n$).

Comment: Tobias Kildetoft, thank you so much. I've arrived at the the desired equality.

Comment: Then I suggest you add an answer with the solution, to remove the question from the unanswered list (and of course to give you some potential reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Let $d := $ gcd($m,n$) $=$ gcd($k,n$). Then $k = k^\prime d$ and $m = m^\prime d$, where $k^\prime$, $m^\prime$ are integers.

Thus $a^k = (a^d)^{k^\prime}$ and $a^m = (a^d)^{m^\prime}$. So $$\langle a^k \rangle \subset \langle a^d \rangle$$ and $$\langle a^m \rangle \subset \langle a^d \rangle.$$

Also, we can write $d = k_0 k + n_1 n = m_0 m + n_2 n$, where $k_0$, $m_0$, $n_1$, $n_2$ are all integers.

We know that $a^n = e$. So $$ a^d = a^{k_0 k + n_1 n} = (a^k)^{k_0},$$ and $$ a^d = a^{m_0 m + n_2 n} = (a^m)^{m_0}.$$
So we can conclude that $$ \langle a^d \rangle \subset \langle a^k \rangle$$ and $$ \langle a^d \rangle \subset \langle a^m \rangle. $$.

Hence $$ \langle a^k \rangle = \langle a^m \rangle = \langle a^d \rangle, $$ as required.